# apt-build & Chromium PPA

Tags: ppa, apt, chromium, build

I'd like to build an (optimized) Version of Chromium for my machine with apt-build on Ubuntu 10.04. I've added a Chromium-PPA to my /etc/sources.list.d/ like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu lucid main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntulucid main
```

But if I run

```
sudo apt-build install chromium browser
```

It tells me

> chromium-browser will not be built because it doesn't have a source package.
>   Missing source package name for source_by_source().

On the other hand
    sudo apt-get source chromium-browser

seems to work fine, even downloads the 6.x from the PPA

What am I doing wrong? Building ffmpeg and firefox via apt-build worked like a breeze. Except that my preferred chromium is from a PPA I don't see a difference.

Comment: Is your deb-src line above just a typo? ".../ubuntulucid main" should be ".../ubuntu lucid main"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the line with the "ubuntulucid" is a typo, the original has those two seperated.

@sagarchalise:
Thats exactly how I installed Chromium and that does work. However, I would like to have it build by apt-build instead of installing the binary version with apt-get. So it doen't work for me. Adding the repository again didn't work for me either.

**EDIT**

Solved! Seems like **apt-build** needs *all* deb-src repositories it should use inside **/etc/apt/sources.list** . By adding the PPA via **apt-add-repository** a separate file for each new repository gets created (inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d). So putting the two line directly into **/etc/sources.list** and running

> sudo apt-build update && sudo apt-build --reinstall install chromium-browser

fixed the issue for me. Thanks for your ideas nonetheless!

**EDIT²**

This [bugreport on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-build/+bug/149360) seems related.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

As for your sources.list.d file give a space besides ubuntu and lucid like this "/ubuntu lucid main" if the same is in your source and its not a typo :)