# (Solved) apt-build Missing source package name for source_by_source()

Tags: apt, compiling, ppa

I installed apt-build and I can not seem to get it working. For example:

```
~$ sudo apt-build --reinstall install boinc-client
Missing source package name for source_by_source().
```

or

```
~$ sudo apt-build install gedit
gedit will not be built because it doesn't have a source package.
Missing source package name for source_by_source().
```

It seems like apt-build is unable is having a problem with the repository. I went and found [a repository for boinc-client][1] to see if that would fix the problem.
I added sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costamagnagianfranco/boinc with success.
I still can't build boinc-client specifically, nor can I build any package.

I have searched google for answers. The most similar issue I found was [apt-build & Chromium PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5170/apt-build-chromium-ppa) which was not helpful to me.

System information:
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Linux Kernel 4.8.0-040800-generic #201610022031 SMP Mon Oct 3 00:32:57 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I just intsalled it Thursday night. I have updated the kernel and installed some software.

Attempting to resolve the issue I edited /etc/apt/sources.list trying to troubleshoot this. This is where I ended.
http://pastebin.com/dDQft3gQ

I am thinking this might be an easy fix, and I lack the experience and or knowledge to do it. Thanks for the help in advance.

SOLUTION: I am using Ubuntu Xenial and if you look at my sources.list it is all over the place, but mostly trusty. I don't think I did that, but who knows. I also didn't notice it yesturday when I asked this question.
Use a sources list generator and correct your sources list to fix the problem.
https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/